# How to find the Limit the row to top 1 in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to limit the output to only get the first row in ORACLE.
I tried `FETCH  first 1 rows only;` But it is giving sql not ended properly error message

Current OUTPUT

```
 70 19-APR-18   Base Line Date
 71 20-JUN-19   Target Date
 73 23-JUN-18
```

QUERY

```
SELECT  EXEC_TRACKER_SESSION_SEQ,
(CASE WHEN tsm.SESSION_SEQ IS NULL THEN tsm.TAGETDATE ELSE s.SESSION_DATE END) as SESSION_DATE
,tsm.NOTES 
FROM TRACKER_SESSION_MAP tsm
LEFT JOIN session s ON tsm.session_seq = s.session_seq
WHERE tsm.TRACKER_SEQ =244
order by TRACKER_SESSION_SEQ ASC
```

Required Output

```
70  19-APR-18   Base Line Date
```

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rownum=1` as :

```
select * from
( 
SELECT  EXEC_TRACKER_SESSION_SEQ,
(CASE WHEN tsm.SESSION_SEQ IS NULL THEN tsm.TAGETDATE ELSE s.SESSION_DATE END) as SESSION_DATE
,tsm.NOTES 
FROM TRACKER_SESSION_MAP tsm
LEFT JOIN session s ON tsm.session_seq = s.session_seq
WHERE tsm.TRACKER_SEQ =244
order by TRACKER_SESSION_SEQ ASC
) 
where rownum=1;
```

Alternatively you may use `row_number()` function as :

```
select * from
(
 SELECT  EXEC_TRACKER_SESSION_SEQ,
(CASE WHEN tsm.SESSION_SEQ IS NULL THEN tsm.TAGETDATE ELSE s.SESSION_DATE END) as SESSION_DATE
,tsm.NOTES, row_number() over (order by day) as rn 
FROM TRACKER_SESSION_MAP tsm
LEFT JOIN session s ON tsm.session_seq = s.session_seq
WHERE tsm.TRACKER_SEQ =244
order by TRACKER_SESSION_SEQ ASC
) 
where rn=1;
```

`fetch..rows` statement works provided that you use `Oracle 12c`.

Comment: So there is no way to add rownum = 1 where clause in the same query , i will have to make the selection once again?

Comment: Your first rownum version was right; your modified version will get a random/indeterminate row, as without the subquery the order-by is applied *after* it's filtered to a single row - which will be the first one it sees, based on however the optimiser executes the rest of the query. (In the row-number one you don't really need the order-by clause, but what is the 'day' in the `over` clause? Should that be `tracker_session_seq`?)

Comment: I had already tried the first option Barbaros before adding the query in stackoverflow, but its not giving me correct values, never mind i will go with the second option only.

Comment: @AlexPoole sure thanks you're right, the keywords `random/indeterminate` are important about this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You need

`WHERE ROWNUM=1`

Oracle doesn't have a `top X` function, but it always knows what the `rownumber`, so take advantage.

Comment: I directly tried adding this to the query, but it didnt work. It gives me wrong result

Comment: Have you taken your order by out of the inner query and put it into the outer query?